# Changing default IDE for editing Validation code in ArcToolbox?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, arctoolbox

Do you know a way that I can change the application that opens the validation scripts in ArcGIS 10.2? At the moment hitting Edit... opens up Notepad, which ain't that friendly an  IDE.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question!

*For later reference*...the default IDE is controlled in the Geoproessessing Options:

[image]

Set the IDE by navigating to the exe for your chosen IDE, in my case PyScripter.
Hit OK to apply new settings.

[image]

So now when I hit Edit... on a toolbox I get this instead :-)

[image]